# Always horizontally scroll images (marquee)

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

guys i have a situation where i have some images which needs to be scrolling horizontally continuously until focused on it.

I have looked into some links in SO where a textview can be done like that using `marquee`.But i need images to be done like that.

```
image 1 image 2 image 3
```

these 3 images should be scrolling continuously until its focused and on focused click on one image which transfer control to particular activity.

how to acheive this.please help

Comment: refer this github site. [https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo) you can get a clear idea about auto scrolling of images.

Answer (score 1):

use images in the Gallery view.move to next position using some method called setposition(int) until the any one of the image has focus.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: i am very new to android can you please elaborate on that